# Magento 2 : Message Notification not working in chrome browser

Tags: magento-2.0

I had developed "Test Message" extension in Magento 2. In this extension, i create \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface class object and called addSuccess() and addError() Method.

```
$this->messageManager->addSuccess('Custom success message');
$this->messageManager->addError('Custom Error message');
```

But it only works in Firefox. When i run this extension in chrome, success and error message not working ?

Also Magento 2 in-built system messages only display in Firefox. Those system messages are also not display in chrome.
so..It is Magento 2 bug ? and if this not bug then what is solution for this problem ?

Please help me. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to Use addSuccessMessage(),addErrorMessage()

Or
Clear your browser cache and cookies, then try it.